# Magento 2 plus minus buttons edit cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a working module that puts plus minus buttons next to the quantity. But when a user wants to change the amounts from the cart the plus minus buttons are not there.

I know i have to edit the file;

```
module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml
```

but how i tell the module that it has to override the file in core somewere in a XML?

My XML so far:

catalog-product-view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Jilco_plusminknoppen::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Jilco_plusminknoppen::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```